# AKS Ingress-nginx takes no external traffic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an AKS deployed in its own vnet (using Azure CNI instead of Kubenet). In the cluster there is an ingress-nginx deployed by Helm/ArgoCD with the annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: true
```

The LoadBalancer looks good:

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                     TYPE         CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP
ingress.nginx-controller LoadBalancer 10.2.1.55   10.1.2.200
```

- I can curl any of those two IPs from within the cluster (any pod) and they work
- From a VM on the same vnet, i.e. outside the cluster, I can curl any pod directly
- I can curl any of the nginx daemonset pods directly on their internal IPs as well.
- **BUT, I can't curl with the LoadBalancer IPs!**

There is no traffic flowing at all, ends in a network timeout and no requests logs from nginx.

What am I missing? I am out of ideas.

Here's my very simple Helm input.

```
ingress-nginx:
  controller:
    hostPort:
      enabled: true
    kind: DaemonSet
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    publishService:
      enabled: false
    extraArgs:
      default-ssl-certificate: "ingress-nginx/ingress.local"
    service:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    admissionWebhooks:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm doing a simpler configuration with an external facing load balancer, but having the same issue. If exec a curl to the load balancer IP from inside the ingress-nginx-controller pod, the curl gets a response. If I exec the same curl from my own machine, the curl gets no response.

Comment: Yes I did, and the answer was posted within a few minutes in the Reddit Kubernetes user group. I will post the solution here shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the blazingly fast and skillful K8s people in the r/kubernetes Reddit group this problem was solved.

When AKS is created there is a *new* Resource Group created for the cluster, even though you ask Azure to use a specific Resource Group. The new RG is named `MC_rg_[cluster name]`. Within this group there are among other things a health check created and it doesn't work. As long as the health probes aren't working, no traffic will be let through.

The Health Probes are found in the menu
`Insights -> Networking -> Load Balancer -> Kubernetes-internal`

Just by replacing the http/https protocols to TCP in the probes, it started working. But a permanent solution is to set hard paths to the health URLs with the setting:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path: "healthz"
```

Here's an issue documenting the same thing:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8501

Hint: All logs from the cluster will end up in the new RG as well. You can write KQL queries directly to the logs for application logs, metrics, what not.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for the info. I saw that the microsoft site talking about adding ingress-nginx included that line. I didn't realize why they were adding that setting though. Thanks for the explanation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: There is so little documented why, and the whole setup with your own ingress is only documented in a release note more or less.